# RemoveAt from StructArray Ue4

Tags: c++, arrays, unreal-engine4

I struggle a bit with deleting struct from my TArray of structs.My struct contains AudioComponent and float.I was using Array.RemoveAt(index), but what i got from this was only removing half of my struct, which is AudioComponent.
Why is that? My function Removing elements looks like this:

```
void RemoveArrayElement( UAudioComponent AudioComponent )
{
    for( int i=0; i<Array.Num(); i++ )
    {
        if( AudioComponent == Array[i].AudioComponent )
        {
            Array.RemoveAt( i );
        }
    }
}
```

What i want to achieve is completely deleting index, AudioComponent with it's float.

Comment: What do you mean by *"removing half of my struct"*? I don't understand how you can remove half of a struct or how this manifests itself (or how you see it for that matter)

Comment: Let's say Array[0]=Stuct(AudioComponent0,float0).
After I use Array.RemoveAt(0), what i get is
Array[0]=Stuct(some invalid value,float0).

Comment: So the size of the array does not change and the remaining elements in `Array` are not "moved" forward?

Comment: You should not store or copy UObjects by value. Instead use pointers (`UAudioComponent*) and UPOPERTY to prevent them from being destroyed by Garbage Collector. Read More: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Objects/index.html

Comment: Well it looks like the element itself is still there, becouse one param of struct is still valid and accessable even if there is no AudioComponent anymore. And you array is not changing it's size after

Comment: You modify the array while being in loop. It leads to incorrect behaviour. Aslo removing elements changes indexes in Array.  If you have more than 2 elements in Array removing first index 0 forces array to shift all it's other indexes: index 1 will became index 0, index 2 will became index 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code. As others mentioned in comments, you should use pointers. And if I'm not mistaken, you aren't allowed to use construction like this:

```
UPROPERTY()
    TArray<UAudioComponent> invalidArray;
```

You should use UPROPERTY macro, otherwise your properties could and probably will be garbage collected. [UPROPERTY wiki](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/UPROPERTY).

Next thing is that you are changing array over which you are iterating. I wrote few approaches, let's look at them:

```
void RemoveArrayElement(UAudioComponent* AudioComponent)
{
    TArray<UAudioComponent*> audioArray; // array will be initialized somewhere else, this is for demo purpose.


    // you always should check your pointers for validity
    if (!AudioComponent || !AudioComponent->IsValidLowLevel() || AudioComponent->IsPendingKill())
        return;


    // Correct approach 1 (multiple):
    TQueue<UAudioComponent*> toDelete;

    for (int i = 0; i < audioArray.Num(); i++)
    {
        auto item = audioArray[i];
        if (AudioComponent == item || true) // we simulate another condition for multiselect
        {
            toDelete.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }

    // better approach for iteration:
    for (auto item : audioArray)
        if (item == AudioComponent || true) // we simulate another condition for multiselect
            toDelete.Enqueue(item);


    // finalize deletion in approach 1
    UAudioComponent* deleteItem;
    while (toDelete.Dequeue(deleteItem))
        audioArray.Remove(deleteItem);




    // almost correct approach 2 (single) :
    UAudioComponent* foundItem;

    for (auto item : audioArray)
        if (item == AudioComponent)
        {
            foundItem = item;
            break;          // we can skip rest - but we must be sure, that items were added to collection using AddUnique(...)
        }

    if (foundItem)
        audioArray.Remove(foundItem);


    // correct and the best - approach 3 (single)

    audioArray.Remove(AudioComponent);
}
```

Comment: I'm quoting from your wiki link: "Non-UPROPERTY variables will not be counted by the GC system.". So nothing will be garbage collected if it isn't a UPROPERTY.

Answer (score 0):

First keep in mind that comparing two objects does not necessarily lead to the expected result of equality. Using the == operator means executing a function (`bool operator==(L, R);`) that specifies what should happen. So if you did not overload the == operator then you don't know what using it would result to unless you look at the source code where it's defined. Since you want to remove the exact audio component and not an instance of it that looks the same, you want to use pointers in your array. That also helps performance since your are not copying the whole component when calling `RemoveArrayElement(...);` but a single pointer. Also when there are two identical audio components stored in the array and they are at index a and a+1, then removing the audio component at index a the next iteration would skip your second audio component since all upper indexes are decremented by one.